# Retrieve Questions and Answers from SurveyMonkey API

Tags: surveymonkey

I'm trying to get the results from a survey through the API, I know I need a list of respondents Ids and the survey ID. When I use the getResponses method I get the results but all the questions and answers come in numbers (Ids) except the questions with open answers (text). How can I bring the actual questions and answers from an API request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the information received in [get_responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_responses) with the survey structure retrieved with [get_survey_details](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_details).

Note I believe there is an outstanding issue where if questions are deleted from the survey they will no longer be in the get_survey_details response.

Comment: Thank you Miles, with that tip I was able to do what I wanted.